# Django app in heroku and local deployment

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have a django app with the following if else block in my settings.py file

`if` block is getting executed when app runs in heroku , `else` is getting executed when app is in local system, please explain what is this `os.getenviron.get`? and what `MBAIR,False` is used for?

```
import os
if not bool(os.environ.get('MBAIR', False)):

 DEBUG = True
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
else:
   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',  
            'NAME': 'rsdfmsfgjsdk_sdfhsdfh'
            'USER': 'sdfhsdfhsdf',
            'PASSWORD': 'sdhsdfhsdhgfsdf', 
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',  
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.environ.get('MBAIR', False)` searches for an environmental variable called MBAIR.  If it does not exist, it returns False.

So when you use that if statement, you're searching for an environmental variable that you're *assuming* is only set on a heroku server.  If found, it sets DEBUG to FALSE and then uses dj_database_url.config to create the database configuration dictionary with the following arguments:

`DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}`

Otherwise it uses your manually defined database settings.

edit:  you can try this out like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['testvariable'] = "dookie"
>>> os.environ.get('testvariable', False)
'dookie'
>>> os.environ.get('MBAIR', False)
False
>>> os.environ.get('MBAIR', "Hooha")
'Hooha'
```

Also, `False` can be replaced with just about anything.

Comment: how to set env variable MBAIR to true ?

Comment: (See my edit.)  It doesn't set the variable to false. it returns false if it does not exist.  If you want to define the variable, do something like os.environ['variablename'] = "value" / True/ False / Queryset / function / etc....